# Google App Engine + Browser: Round trip time too high

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, browser, google-cloud-endpoints

I am concern about waiting time for browser is high compare to google appengine dispatching request time. How do I reduce round trip time? Any performance tweak at Google App Engine to make reduce it? or anywhere else?

Note: I am also using Google End point, may be it is related.

Network tab timeline:

[image: Timeline]

Google App engine logs

[image: Logs]

Thanks

Comment: I guess its highly depends on your network (provider) and geographic location (be default GAE is in USA, and if you're in Europe -- you will get bigger latency)

Comment: Have you looked at [Cloud Trace](https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-trace) to see how your application is performing?

Comment: @tx802 i checked trace, its the same.. i want to know huge round trip time.